# How can I determine location using GPS?

Tags: objective-c, gps

I move between four adjacent region, Space each region is eight Square meters.

How can I do a program for my Iphone mobile to alert me, if I'm in region one, two, three, or four? In order to do something in that region?

And thank for all.

Comment: I'm not sure civilian GPS gives you sub-8-metre resolution...

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth It can do that if you are in the USA in a city with many Wi-Fi hotspots. And your phone is charging.

Comment: Because of the iOS desire to conserve power, you'll only get high resolution GPS updates if your app is active in the foreground. Also, as Oli mentioned, you won't necessarily get the resolution you want.

Comment: Thank for all. And I need to  bounding certain region by bounding circle latitude and longtitude for this region . Namely if any person entered this region ,I must know that.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at this to learn how to access GPS data:
http://www.vellios.com/2010/08/16/core-location-gps-tutorial/

Then you can probably add a listener that checks for changes, alerting your program if you moved into another "region."

Comment: thank you Mr.eboix. And I need to bounding certain region by bounding circle latitude and longtitude for this region . Namely if any person entered this region ,I must know that....... And I repeat my thanking